# At what age does a male kitten mature physically?

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

[image]I have a 11 week old kitten that I have cared for since it was 2 weeks old. I was told it is male but I have never raised a kitten before so I am not positive. Is there any way I can tell for sure?   (Best picture I can get,sorry)

Comment: To answer the subject line question, a websearch for "kitten mature months" finds statements like "Kittens take about a year to reach adulthood and up to 4 to mature. Your cat will hit puberty around 6 months of age."

Answer (score 1):

11 weeks old you should be able to feel testicles, unless he's a cryptorchid (testicles retained in abdomen) or a female :). 
Feel free to post a picture of his/her genitals.

Comment: Picture looks like a male to me, as far as I can tell thru the fuzz (of the picture, not the kitten).

Comment: Yeah looks male to me too.

Comment: Of course if you are still in doubt you can ask your vet next time the fuzzy one is in for a checkup.

Answer (score 0):

Funniest cat face ever! Poor guy has no eyes. 
Yeah, it's a boy. And he needs to be neutered around 6 or 7 months old. Search for spay/neuter clinics in your area. Also he needs his vaccinations ASAP. Many clinics have a weekly or monthly low cost "shot clinic" which you can ask about.